# How to Configure Chapel/GASNet for running multilocale codes on MXM Infiniband network with Partition Key?

Tags: chapel, infiniband, gasnet

I'm trying to run a multilocale Chapel code on a cluster that has an MXM Infiniband network(40 Gbps, model: Mellanox Technologies MT26428).

I followed both Chapel and GASNet documentations, and I set

`export CHPL_COMM_SUBSTRATE=ibv`

`export CHPL_LAUNCHER=gasnetrun_ibv`

`export GASNET_IBV_SPAWNER=mpi`

instead of using `CHPL_COMM_SUBSTRATE=mxm`, once mxm is deprecated.

The problem is that I can build Chapel using the ibv substrate. But, I cannot run on multiple locales. I receive a huge number of timeout errors.

In the first place, I thought the problem was the PKEY. So, I added `"--mca btl_openib_pkey "0x8100""` to the `MPIRUN_CMD`. But, no success.

I also tried to use the deprecated mxm configuration:

`CHPL_LAUNCHER=gasnetrun_mxm`

`export CHPL_LAUNCHER=gasnetrun_ibv`

`export GASNET_MXM_SPAWNER=mpi`

However, I cannot build Chapel with such a configuration. That's the error message:

`"User requested --enable-mxm, but I don't know how to build mxm programs for your system."`

By the way, using GASNET on top of MPI, UDP, and Infiniband without a Partition Key works just fine.

Does anybody know how to use Chapel on a Cluster equipped with an MXM Infiniband network and Partition Key (PKEY)?

Best Regards,

Tiago Carneiro.

Comment: In your initial setup that runs, but just times out, what output do you get when running with the --verbose flag (which should show the underlying commands used to launch the program)?

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to rebuild chapel with support for IB and make sure that all the libraries that are required(I don't use chapel, so I know little about the build process) are in the correct spots during the initial install or build.  Doing a quick google search would lead me to believe you need to have a correctly installed OFED implementation, I would recommend Mellanox unless there is a reason not to use that.  Make sure you have the full OFED installed and it might have the legacy packages you need.

Comment: Hello Brado. Using the IBV spawner as ``SSH``, building and compilling the distributed hello world, I get: ``*** FATAL ERROR: failed to connect (snd) status=12``. In turn, using MPI as the spawner and without passing the PKEY with --mca, I get ``too many retries sending message to 0x0027:0x00003a15, giving up``. Finally, passing the correct PKEY to MPI, I get ``mpirun noticed that process rank 8 with PID 19647 on node uvb-20 exited on signal 6 (Aborted).``.  What makes me curious is that the ``make`` says that cannot build for MXM. Is this configuration missing in Chapel?

Comment: Hello Matt. I did that.  I made an script for MXM network, then, I rebuilt Chapel and  the distributed example. The problem is that I receive the following message: ``"User requested --enable-mxm, but I don't know how to build mxm programs for your system."``. I do not understant why. Is this configuration is missing inside Chpl third-party code? I took a look, the number of files is the same. Moreover, I'll try to download the OFED software. I just dont know whether I can install this software in a instance of a cluster.

Comment: Hi Tiago — We don't have much experience using MXM or PKEYs on my team.  The message about "I don't know how to build mxm programs for your system" is almost certainly coming from GASNet rather than from Chapel ('git grep'ping the sources shows hits in the gasnet sources), and I suspect that the other issues you're running into are ones you'd hit trying to get any GASNet program to run on the system.  Have you had luck building a GASNet-only hello world program for this system (using either a standalone version or the one bundled with Chapel)?  I've asked the GASNet team for ideas as well.

Comment: Hello Brad! Thank you for your reply. I'll do very soon this task you suggested. I'll build a hello-world from GASNet. I'll also try to build for other clusters, as I'm also facing problems with other networks. Thank you again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tiago,

As the author and maintainer of GASNet's ibv-conduit (support for libibverbs) I can tell you that we have never had support for a non-default PKey.  The message `*** FATAL ERROR: failed to connect (snd) status=12` is consistent with use of the wrong PKey.

Based on your question here, I have made an attempt to provide support for a user-specified PKey.  You can find my prototype as a pull-request in the GASNet git repository at Bitbucket:  https://bitbucket.org/berkeleylab/gasnet/pull-requests/248 (or https://bitbucket.org/PHHargrove/gasnet-public/commits/ibv-pkey/raw to get just a raw patch).  You should be able to apply the one commit in that PR in the `third-party/gasnet/gasnet-src` directory of the Chapel source.  I don't have a partitioned IB network to test on.  So, you would be helping me out if you can verify this resolves your problem.

Regarding `User requested --enable-mxm, but I don't know how to build mxm programs for your system`, I suspect that GASNet's configure probe was unable to find the necessary headers or libraries.  Details of the failure should be in a `config.log` file below `third-party/gasnet/build`.  If your mxm headers and libs are installed in a location other than `/opt/mellanox/mxm` then you can set the environment variable `MXM_HOME` when building Chapel, to inform GASNet's configure script of the actual location.  However, I am not aware of any PKey support in libmxm.  So, this might be a dead end.

-Paul

Comment: Hello Paul, thank you for your reply! I can apply and test on my network within three days. Then, I'm going to reply, ok? Concerning the headers, I'm going to build it and a standalone version of GASNet, as well. Thank you again!

Comment: Hello Paul. I'm trying to apply your changes to Chapel's source code. However, I cannot find your modifications in branch `develop` after cloning GASNet. What branch should I clone? Thank you.

Comment: Hello Tiago, the changes are in a pull-request (linked in my answer) and will not be accepted into develop until you have confirmed they are correct.  Please try the following, starting in the unmodified Chapel source directory
`cd third-party/gasnet/gasnet-src && wget -q -O - https://bitbucket.org/PHHargrove/gasnet-public/commits/ibv-pkey/raw | patch -p1`

Comment: Hello Paul - good news, It works! First I modified the command: `cd .../gasnet-scr/ibv-conduit`. Then, I had to export `GASNET_IBV_PKEY='0x8100'`, which is my pkey. Otherwise, the connection returns `status=12`. Finally, it is necessary to manually set `MPIRUN_CMD="...  --mca btl_openib_pkey "0x8100" ..."` in case `GASNET_IBV_SPAWNER=mpi`. Thank you again for your patience and time!